# installing nodeclipse returning error

Tags: node.js, eclipse, installation, nodeclipse

[image]

I am getting this error when installing using `MARKETPLACE (RECOMMENDED WAY: A BIT QUICKER)`. I am doing the tutorial from [here](http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/) and I am following ***A) MARKETPLACE (RECOMMENDED WAY: A BIT QUICKER)***

In the dialog box what I did is click the `Select All` button

`FYI`

I want to use nodeJS in eclipse that is why I want to install nodeclipse. For creating cordova.

> **How to fix this error**

1. OS- windows 10
2. Java version - version 8 update 65
3. Eclipse Version - 4.3.0
4. Node.JS version - Latest I think

Comment: You should specify OS, Java version, Eclipse Version and Node.JS version

Comment: @ArifKhan please see update

Comment: You may run `node -v` from cmd to know nodejs version. By the way, you should run eclipse as Administrator and then try to install nodeeclipse

Comment: @ArifKhan when i run the eclipse as admin it works can you provide that as answer so other with same problem can come here to see a prossible solution?

Comment: @ArifKhan when i run `node -v` i get `'node' is not a recognized as an internal or external command .......` from command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **run eclipse as administrator** because `nodeclipse` require write permission

You may like to install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and set path for it

`Update`

To set up path do as follows:

You need to Add C:\Program Files\nodejs to your PATH environment variable. To do this follow these steps:

1. Use the global Search Charm to search "Environment Variables"
2. Click "Edit system environment variables"
3. Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog.
4. In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include C:\Program Files\nodejs. Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a ;.

**Note:**

You will have to restart any currently-opened command prompts before it will take effect.

Comment: how to set the path sorry it wasnt in the link you provided?

Comment: Have you installed node.js and able to run `node -v`? If you are able to run `node -v` then path already set.

Comment: v4.6.0 many thanks mate. im sure many will be helped by this answer